# How to redirect into a random ID from another controller?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

My project is a review site about movies, series and actors.
I already have the movies, series and actors views done (index, details, edit and delete), with the correct controllers and everything. But now I am trying to create "Generate random movie" and a "Generate random serie" buttons in the home view, so that when I click in that button, it redirects me into a random movie/serie.

So the URL should go from `Home/Index` to `Movies/Details/"Random Id"`(the same for series).

I dont have anything in the Home Controller, except the return View() in the index class.

So i would like to know, what should i put into the controller and into the Actionlink/button to redirect it to the random movie.

Edit:

Models:
Movie Model:

```
public class MovieViewModel
    {
        public int MovieID { get; set; }
        public string MovieName { get; set; }
        public string MovieDescription { get; set; }
        public string MovieCategory { get; set; }
        public string MovieYear { get; set; }
    }
```

Serie Model:

```
public class SeriesViewModel
    {
        public int SerieID { get; set; }
        public string SerieName { get; set; }
        public string SerieCategory { get; set; }
        public string SerieDescription { get; set; }
        public string SerieYear { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the details View from Movies (Series is pretty much the same)

```
<div>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            <p>Movie Name: </p>
            <p> </p>


        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MovieName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            <p>Movie Description: </p>
            <p> </p>


        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MovieDescription)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            <p>Category: </p>
            <p> </p>


        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MovieCategory)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            <p>Year of the movie: </p>
            <p> </p>


        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MovieYear)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.MovieID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

Comment: Can you provide more Razor code? Without it, we do not know how you can get the id you are missing.

Comment: @CiubotariuFlorin I will Edit the question

Answer (score 2):

You need to add '/' in url

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Something", "/Movies/Details")
```

Comment: It outputs this URL: `Home/Movies/Details`. I want to "quit" the Home controller and go to MoviesController

Comment: then you must need to go on root first. @Html.ActionLink("Something", "~/Movies/Details") , append tilde

Comment: it redirects to this URL: `http://localhost:****/Home/~/Movies/Details`

Comment: could you please share your RouteConfig.cs ?

Comment: sure, I will add it to the question. its the one that comes with MVC

Answer (score 1):

So,

First you need in your home view a link to the controller that will generate your random page, this line was sent by Saqib abbas

```
@Html.ActionLink("Something", "/Movies/Details")
```

next on your MoviesController

create a method

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
    // First we'll determine if we return a movie or a serie 
    Random movieOrSerie = new Random();
    int movieOrSerie = random1.Next(1, 2);

    if(movieOrSerie == 1) // if 1 we'll search for a random Movie
    {
        var movies = //get your list of movies here
        Random movieIndex = new Random();
        int movieIndex = random1.Next(0, movies.Count);
        var movie = movies.ElementAt(movieIndex);
    }
    else // same for series
    {
        var series = //get your list of series here
        Random serieIndex = new Random();
        int serieIndex = random1.Next(0, series.Count);
        var serie = series.ElementAt(serieIndex);
    }
    // then you have to put the serie or movie in your viewModel 
    return View("ViewName", ViewModel)
}
```

this is not the prettiest way, send us your Movie Serie and maybe the parent class(if exist), the model and the view of the Details page and I ll update this answer.

Comment: I dont have a class especifically for the Movie and Serie. I have a full controller for each of them. Do you want me to put any speciphic part of the controller in here? (I will update, with what I know I can give you right now).

Comment: so movies and series are stored in the same table ? but you have 2 controller ? why not use the same controller and the same page ?

Comment: oh wait, im so confused. nah, I have 2 different tables. The models are in the question

Comment: like, there is no way to just redirect to the Movies Controller, Details and then a random ID of the table?

Answer (score 0):

If you have another controller named `MoviesController` I recommend you to write your anchor as

`@Html.ActionLink("ActionLinkName", "Details", "Movies", new { id = item.MovieID });`

That means you want to generate a link to a method named `Details` inside `MoviesController` which accepts a parameter named `id`.

Comment: okay, I´ve tried your method, but I dont have anything in my controller yet, so I dont know if it will work. I would put some code in the controller, but I have to figure out how to do it for series and movies at the same time (which I dont know yet).

Comment: Can you give us more details about the problem? Do you want to create an action link to a controller which does not exist at the moment?

Comment: can you send us your classes Serie and Movie, I suppose the problem his that you don't know how to generate the random Id and then generate the needed view, am I wrong ?

Comment: @matt its pretty similar to what you said. I will edit the question to a more detailed question.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your code, try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Random Movie Generator</h2>
        <p>

        </p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Somethin", "Movies","Details",new { id = item.MovieID},new {@class= "btn btn-success" })
    </div>
```

This will also make your link look like an actual button.